# Is there a way to set mixin data?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, howler.js

I'm working with vue-howler and for some reason, the data there is being passed using mixin, I don't see a way to access such mixin from the vue file script (much less do I find a way to change the data in it)

I want to show the progress of playing a music file in a vuetify slider, but due to being contained in a mixin, i get an error "Computed property was assigned to but it has no setter."

```html
//MusicPlayerComponent.vue
<template>
    <v-card flat width="500px" height="200px">
      <v-flex class="info d-flex justify-center">

        <v-btn icon large @click="togglePlayback">
          <v-icon>
            {{ playing ? 'mdi-pause' : 'mdi-play' }}
          </v-icon>
        </v-btn>

        <v-slider v-model="progress" min="0" max="100">
          
        </v-slider>
    </v-card>
</template>
```

I don't need to show the script section of my vue file because there is literally nothing there, the "progress, playing, togglePlayback" properties and functions in the above code all come from that "mixin"

```ts
//MusicPlayerComponent.vue

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Watch} from "vue-property-decorator"
// @ts-ignore
import VueHowler from 'vue-howler'

@Component({
  mixins: [VueHowler]
})


export default class AudioPlayerComponent extends Vue {

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`seek`](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#seekseek-id) property of vue-howler to get/set the position of playback for a sound. See [docs](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js) for more props and options